# Testing registry path and creating key if not found

Tags: powershell, registry

I have a script that I'm trying to run across a portion of my environment that will get the mcafee agent version and install a registry fix if a registry key is not found. I'm able to get the McAfee part down right and the query of the key but I can't get it to install if it isn't located. 
Below is my code:

```
$Servers = "Testserver01"
ForEach($Server in $Servers){
    REG QUERY "\\$Server\HKLM\SOFTWARE\McAfee\DLP\Agent" /v AgentVersion
    $Spectre= REG QUERY "\\$Server\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" /v FeatureSettingsOverrideMask
    If($Spectre -match "False" -or $null){
          REG Add "\\$Server\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" /v FeatureSettingsOverrideMask /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f
    }
    Else {
          Write-Host "Installing Key"
    }
}
```

Error didn't load sorry, here is the error I get, it doesn't seem to install the key and it's value

[image]

So I got closer, using OpenSubKey I was able to get the process started, how can I get the value of the Agent version? Here is what I have...

```
$Server = "Test01"
$reg=
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Server)
$regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\McAfee\DLP\Agent')
if($regKey -eq $null){echo "NO KEY"} else {$regKey.GetValueNames()}
```

[image]

Comment: What goes wrong? Do you get errors? Does nothing happen? Is the wrong thing written? Does your left big toe cramp up and you have to take your shoe off right there in the office embarassing everyone around you? Help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pure Powershell version would probably something like this:

```
$Servers = "Testserver01"
$regPath = 'HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management'
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {
    If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server {
            Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\McAfee\DLP\Agent' -Name 'AgentVersion'
            If (-not (Test-Path -Path $using:regPath)) {
                New-Item -Path $Using:regPath -ItemType Directory
            }
            New-ItemProperty -Path $using:regPath -Name 'FeatureSettingsOverrideMask' -Value 3 -PropertyType REG_DWORD
        }
    }
}
```

First you check if the server is reachable and then you query the agent version and create the registry setting you specified. You might add a check if the fix you plan to "install" is already in place.

Comment: `if($regKey -eq $null)` this does not work as you might think it does. The better way to test this would be `if(-not ($regKey))`